# data loader concatenate transform data from csv without changing csv

Tags: apex, data-loader, data

we have a scenario where we will be getting input data in csv files. we need to load these in custom objects in salesforce. we do not want to edit these csv files. there are scenarios where we need to fill sObject field with concatenated data from multiple cells of a row from csv. in some cases, we need to do some custom calculations on some fields and load sObject field with the value of an formula like expression which can take inputs from multiple cells of a row from csv. we dont have any ETL tool. does data loader support this type of custom transformation , concatenation etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apex Data Loader does not support data transformation, concatenation of columns from CSV. Hence we did some data massaging within our excel sheet using formulas. Other option was to load data from csv files as is and then have some triggers to do the data concatenation, transformation etc before records are being inserted. 
But we decided to do it in Excel.